# How to trigger hook_form_alter() on my custom $form?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

I have written a custom module which builds a custom `user_profile_form()`:

```
mymodule_user_profile_form($form, $form_state, $user) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
  $form = user_profile_form($form, $form_state, $user, 'account');
  // doing stuff with $form ...
  return $form;
}
```

Now, it's working as desired but I noticed a lot of contrib modules are altering the `user_profile_form()` calling a `hook_form_alter()` on the `$form_id == 'user_profile_form'`.

Now, I want all these modifications applied to my custom profile form, too. How to achieve that?

The hacky way would be to go through all modules and change the checks for `$form_id == 'user_profile_form' || $form_id == 'mymodule_user_profile_form'`, but this is a no-go and I would appreaciate a clean way to do this. Any idea?

---

**Update**: `drupal_get_form()` is not the answer as it is not working as desired. This is only returning the $form object without re-building it which causes many issues with theming layer and `$form_state['values']`. I'm adding this information as requested by moderator, but this is *not* part of my question. This is the not working code with `drupal_get_form()` [b6d1f1d8](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-donschoe-2270791/tree/user_revision_edit.module?id=b6d1f1d839bb6fdc8f99354b94bf9bc01c1b25f0#n223) and this is the working code with `user_profile_form()` [d5d43dc0](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-donschoe-2270791/tree/user_revision_edit.module?id=d5d43dc06b97fdb52e8684ade615a0905cfd4e1e#n223).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `drupal_get_form($form_id)` to get the form instead of directly calling `user_profile_form()` and it will ensure that all the form alters are applied before you get the form.

**Update**:
          Can you explain why you are not using `hook_form_alter()`?

But if you want to proceed this way, then instead of calling `drupal_get_form()` you can replace that with the code from `drupal_build_form()`, except the call to `drupal_process_form()`,

Replace `drupal_get_form()` with the following code, copied from `drupal_build-form()`

```
$form_state += form_state_defaults();
if (!isset($form_state['input'])) {
   $form_state['input'] = $form_state['method'] == 'get' ? $_GET : $_POST;
}
$form = drupal_retrieve_form('user_profile_form', $form_state);
drupal_prepare_form('user_profile_form', $form, $form_state);
```

Comment: `drupal_get_form()` is not *building* the form and is a total mess for the user profile form, for example the $form_state is not populated correctly and theming layer is broken. I need to build the form from scratch.

Comment: what do you mean by it is not building the form?, can you post your code and also the return value of `drupal_get_form()`

Comment: Reference to full code history: This is not working [b6d1f1d8](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-donschoe-2270791/tree/user_revision_edit.module?id=b6d1f1d839bb6fdc8f99354b94bf9bc01c1b25f0#n223) with `drupal_get_form()` the `$form_state['values']` are empty after `_submit()` - and this fixed it: [d5d43dc0](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-donschoe-2270791/tree/user_revision_edit.module?id=d5d43dc06b97fdb52e8684ade615a0905cfd4e1e#n223) calling directly the form builder. There are similar discussions on the internet.

Comment: @vertoe I'm struggling to understand - is your problem sorted? If so, would be so kind as to put an answer in detailing how you fixed it? If not, could you update the question and make it clear why the approach in the second link in your previous comment didn't work? Would be nice to get the question closed off is all; thanks

Comment: @vertoe I have tested the code, you gave, with `drupal_get_form()` and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Clive this is not solving my problem and we were discussing why. I can add this information to the original question. It's still open.

Comment: @vertoe are you using the `user_revision_edit` module that you gave? or are you using it as a reference?

Comment: @wolverine I'm using and developing it. My question is how this module can trigger all the changes from the user profile form without using the `drupal_get_form()` function.

Comment: In simple terms: reproduce drupal_get_form, but add a custom value to the $form_state before invoking drupal_build_form. Then implement hook_form_alter for the user profile form, and only make changes if $form_state contains that custom value. A little 'round the houses', but it'll work

Comment: @vertoe can you explain why you are not using `hook_form_alter()`.

Comment: @vertoe I have updated the answer